# How can I change styled components theme, when className is generated dynamically?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I try to apply Styled Components to my React code with TypeScript.
Now my `render()` method generates multiple elements with loop, and each element's className is generated dynamically by another method.

```
render() {
    try {
      const {steps} = this.props;
      return (
        <div className="step-bar">
          {steps.map((s, i) => (
            <div key={i} className={this.getClassName(i)}>
              {s}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      );
    } catch(e) {
      utils.sendErrorObject(e);
      return null;
    }
  };
```

Now I want to apply Styled Component to this code and handle multiple styles according to `className`, but I don't know how to specify the condition because `className` is dynamic in the code.
Anyone knows good idea?

Comment: in what way do you want to integrate styled component? replacing `<div key={i} className={this.getClassName(i)}>` with `<YourStyledComponent key={i} className={this.getClassName(i)}>` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const MyStyledComponent = styled.div`
   background-color: ${props => ~props.className.indexOf('current') ? 'red' : 'blue'}
`

...

render() {
   return <MyStyledComponent className={this.getClassName(i)}>Text</MyStyledComponent>
}
```

Comment: The result of getClassName is like “step” or “step__current” etc, and I want to change the background color when the className includes “current”.

Comment: check this toggle solution, it worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/984471